# YII2 - dropdownlist not being submitted in post

Tags: post, drop-down-menu, yii2

I'm new to yii and i'm using a dropdownlist to list some products that i need in my controller.

Here is the view code:

```php
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($company, 'dot_com_name')->staticInput() ?>
    <p> You have: <p>

    <?php echo $balance ?>   

    <?= $form->field($product,'dot_prod_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(
            Product::find()->where(['dot_prod_com' =>$company->dot_com_id])->all(), 
           'dot_prod_id','dot_name'
        ), ['prompt' => 'Select']
    ) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Redeem', ['class' => 'share']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

In my controller:

```php
$product = new Product;
if ($product->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
    echo "<script type ='text/javascript'>" .
         "alert('ID USER: ".$product->dot_prod_id."');" .
         "</script>";
    echo $product->dot_prod_id;
}
```

The alert and the echo doesn't return anything except blank spaces. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Fortran but I already solved it.

For massive assignment using model->load, model attributes must be set safe. Setup these attributes implicitly as safe in your model rules, in case you do not have other rules or scenarios set for these:

```php
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['dot_prod_id'], 'safe'],
    ];    
}
```